# How to create a dynamic INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I need to create dynamic INNER JOIN (I believe I need to anyway). I have 4 tables pears, apples, oranges, bananas. I used all the same column names in those 4 tables.

Another 2 tables 'fruit' and 'fruitcomments'

```
pears    apples    oranges   bananas
-------------------------------------
id
user
photo
comment
date
```

For the Fruits table typeid relates to other tables 1=pear, 2=apples, 3=oranges, 4=banana.
Itemid correlates to the id of either pears, apples, oranges or bananas.

```
Fruit 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
fruitsid
typeid
itemid
```

How would I go about selecting the top 10 from the fruit table and dynamically get the matching row from the corresponding table

Working Code

```
SELECT TOP (10) fruitId, id, user, photo, comment FROM 
(
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN PEARS T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=1
UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN APPLES T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=2
UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN ORANGES T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=3
UNION ALL 
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN BANANAS T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=4
)a
ORDER BY fruitId DESC
```

OLD NON-Working Code:

```
SELECT TOP (10) id, user, photo, comment FROM
(

SELECT f.typeid, f.itemid, a.id, a.user, a.photo, a.comment FROM Fruit f INNER JOIN a on f.item=a.id

--excuse the gibberish. I never used CASE before
case when f.typeid=1 then
(SELECT id, user, photo, comment FROM Pears WHERE id=f.itemid)a
case when f.typeid=2 then
(SELECT id, user, photo, comment FROM Apples WHERE id=f.itemid)a
case when f.typeid=3 then
(SELECT id, user, photo, comment FROM Oranges WHERE id=f.itemid)a
case when f.typeid=4 then
(SELECT id, user, photo, comment FROM Bananas WHERE id=f.itemid)a
)
```

Something like that, but I dont know how to express it correctly. Expected results below by selecting top (3) from following 'fruit' table order by fruitsid DESC.

```
fruits
-----------
fruitsid   typeid     itemid
22         1          19
23         3          73
24         2          46

pears
--------------
id     user     photo    comment    date
19     tom      1.jpg    hi         2012-06-01 12:00:00.000
22     bill     5.jpg    hello      2012-06-01 13:00:00.000

apples
--------------
id     user     photo    comment
46     sam      78.jpg   howdy
22     bill     5.jpg    hello

bananas
--------------
id     user     photo    comment
32     tom      1.jpg    hi
73     bill     5.jpg    hello

oranges
--------------
id     user     photo    comment
73     jane     55.jpg   wave
22     bill     5.jpg    hello

results
-------------
19     tom      1.jpg    hi 
73     bill     5.jpg    hello
46     sam      78.jpg   howdy
```

IO Stats on 4 rows using UNION ALL with newer code

```
(4 row(s) affected)
Table 'pears'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'fruit'. Scan count 3, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'apples'. Scan count 1, logical reads 16, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'oranges'. Scan count 1, logical reads 115, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

At least there wasn't one physical read which is awesome

Comment: The chosen answer works, but you might want to reconsider your schema.  Why have four tables to store the same data?  Try reworking the tables with only Fruit and FruitComment.  Hard-coded an id in a query (typeid) is a sign of bad schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is by using UNION to join each -

```
SELECT TOP (10) fruitId, id, user, photo, comment FROM 
(
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN PEARS T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=1
UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN APPLES T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=2
UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN ORANGES T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=3
UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.fruitsId, T2.id, T2.user, T2.photo, T2.comment 
    FROM FRUITS T1 LEFT JOIN BANANAS T2 ON (T1.itemId=T2.id)
    WHERE T1.typeId=4
)
ORDER BY fruitId DESC
```

If you dont want to include records which exists only in `Fruits` but not in `PEAR|APPLES|ORACNGES|BANANAS` then use `INNER JOIN` instead

Comment: Wouldn't that query each of the four tables every time or would SQL just drop the tables that don't correspond to the typeid?

Comment: well the queries has clause of typeid so the result is narrowed down

Comment: I think you're on the right track, I just need to figure out an IF ELSEIF scheme for the middle section

Comment: well this is one of the solution..not very sure if its possible the way you trying to do using `CASE`. I see your point that CASE will not hit all the tables... but if you noticed, the SELECT query inside case gets fired for each record which is an bigger impact on performance

Comment: I'll programmatically run a few thousand queries and attach the stats IO to see the performance tomorrow

Comment: I went with UNION ALL because it's suppose to be faster than UNION. You're right, I cant use CASE in a FROM clause.

Comment: yes you are right...UNION ALL will be a better option here...updating the answer accordingly.